# Do Mobs Despawn in Minecraft 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do mobs despawn in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21444/when-do-mobs-despawn-in-minecraft)

I know that mobs are despanwed in earlier versions of the [game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21444/when-do-mobs-despawn-in-minecraft). I heard that in the new 1.8 update that mobs are no longer despawned or are saved when they are despawned? Is this true?