# How do i get charged creepers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need help making a charged creeper! I tried a metal pole and creepers but that didn't work. I have seen them be spawned by a dropper but nothing else. I'm not entirely sure if they exist in vanilla Mine craft or not. It may come in a mod but if it's possible to get it in vanilla please help me.

Comment: Metal actually has no effect on how frequently lightning strikes in MineCraft, and as far as I know, no other material does either.

Comment: um, I'm sure you can spawn them with Command Blocks is 1.7.2, and that's about it.

Comment: No idea if it helps with Minecraft logic, but you could try getting them to the highest point you can to increase their chances of getting struck...my question is why would you WANT to meet such a creeper?

Answer (score 7):

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper#Charged_Creepers)

> A charged Creeper is created when lightning strikes within 3 - 4 blocks of a normal Creeper

You will know it works when the creeper has a blue aura around it.

Getting the creeper struck by lightning is the hard part.  You will likely need lots of luck if you want to avoid finding a mod that will charge one for you.  [You can see this answer for odds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/64045/42984)

If you want to use a mod, [CommandBook](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/commandbook/) can offer you Thor's hammer to call down lightning strikes with the `thor <player>` command.  It is also Bukkit compatible.

Answer (score 3):

As [David Starkley pointed out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/123752/17179), a charged creeper occurs when lightning strikes near a creeper. Although possible, it is extraordinarily improbable that it happens naturally in front of your eyes.

However, you can increase those odds significantly using some tricks by YouTuber Docm77, who was able to pull it off without any mods, map editors, or even creative mode:

- [YouTube: Minecraft - Producing Power Creepers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XU3_UrSRTQ) (video showing off the results)
- [YouTube: Docm77´s NEW Minecraft World Tour : Episode 76: Crazy Cats and Power Creepers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts-WV06XimQ) (video where he explains a bit about the mob trap)
- [YouTube: Docm77´s NEW Minecraft World Tour : 77th Episode Special](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGrni2v9m0s) (another video where he explains the mob trap. The explanation begins at around 1hr 5min.)

Comment: Could you include a summary of the tricks in these videos for those of us who cannot watch them ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

To get charged (actually called supercharged) creepers, a lighting bolt has to land within 4 blocks of them. Also, via [McEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) or other mods/clients, you are able to have supercharged spawn eggs and supercharged spawners.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Creepers turn into charged creepers when struck by lightning. Pigs turn into Zombie Pig Men when struck by lightning. When a charged creeper explodes it make a large explosion than a regular creeper would.

You can't create them in vanilla minecraft. You have to be patient and wait for lightning to strike. I've only ever seen one in minecraft vanilla once, they are very rare.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This answer brings nothing that have not already been said. Please avoid duplicating content and only provide answers that add something new.

Comment: @Jupotter Technically it adds some new info.  My answer assumes you know what a Charged Creeper is/does.  As far as OP though, you are right it does not add helpful information to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible ways to get a charged creeper is for lightning to strike near it or you use a spawner in NEI to spawn one. Some mods also allow different ways, but I don't know which those are. If you want to spawn one yourself, install Not Enough Items, it gives you every mob spawner possible.