# Will zombies die if I put a light in their house?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a house for my zombie friends. Their house is dark which makes other mobs spawn there. So if I make a house and move my zombies in there and put torches will they die because of the light or not?

Answer (score 5):

**No** they won't die, however, if you don't do something to make sure they don't despawn, like give them a nametag, then they will just despawn when you get too far away, regardless of the light.

Answer (score 5):

Torches don't hurt Zombies at all (but will prevent more from spawning), only Sunlight does direct harm. Though take note that [hostile mobs like Zombies despawn when a chunk is unloaded](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21444/when-do-mobs-despawn-in-minecraft) ([though this can be prevented with the Name Tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Name_Tag) apparently, thanks Unionhawk), so they'll eventually disapear if the chunk is unloaded (which it will be in normal play), and the light will prevent other mobs from spawning in their place.

Answer (score 0):

Zombies won't die from "Block" type lightning,which includes torches. Zombies will did just in direct contact with the sunlight,not from a torch. But a torch can prevent more hostile mobs. Stay close to the zombies,otherwise they will despawn,unless you name them with a name tag.